# Can the body delay infections/sickness for important reasons?

Tags: immune-system, disease

Background of the question: I worked on a very important project which was also critical for the firm and would have affected the employment permanently if it failed. During that time several coworkers were sick, but I never felt sick at all.

Finally the project is finished and I go into my well-earned holiday. Despite being well on the last day I suddenly felt woozy on the first day of the holiday. The very next day the big, big hammer was coming down, fever, shivering, cold and pain all over the body (My stomach was ok and I wasn't queasy, only spaced out) . I really, *really* felt miserable and nearly slept all day.
The very next day the symptoms are receding and I am feeling better now. Both the sudden onset and the sudden recovery are unusual.

**So, is the body able to delay a disease if it is very important?**

I remember a claim that some statistics indicate that on important days (New Year, Easter, religious days in common, birthday, anniversary etc.) people are both less prone to die before the day and more prone to die after the day.